# Adding external .jar to androidstudio project

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

I've added the external library `bsh-2.0b4.jar` to an android project in android-studio by going into `Project structure -> Modules -> myProject -> Tab-Dependencies -> + Sign` and then add the .jar file.
I also tried to copy the file into the /libs directory and then rightclick in studio and `add as library...` (both methods independently!!). I inserted the following code as a test

```
  import bsh.Interpreter;
  ...
  Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
  interpreter.eval("result = (7+21*6)/(32-27)");
  return interpreter.get("result").toString();
```

I compile with the buildin button in android.
The build.gradle looks like:

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
  }
  apply plugin: 'android'

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  android {
     compileSdkVersion 17
     buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

     defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
     }
  }

  dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
  }
```

But when I compile everything I receive the error

```
  Gradle: error: package bsh does not exist
  Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class Interpreter
```

Can anyone help me pls?

Comment: how do you compile ? using command line or built-in command ? Can you post the dependencies section of build.gradle ?

Comment: Updated the gradle file, and I'm compiling with the build-in command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your dependencies like that

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
   compile 'org.beanshell:bsh:2.0b4'
}
```

You can now remove manually downloaded dependencies in `libs` directory.

What you did was adding libraries to Android Studio project only. You should always add them to Gradle build files as only this is interpreted by Android Build Tools.

There is also new version of build tools 18.0.1, you can install them and change version in you `build.gradle`. As far as I know they can handle `aar` dependencies better.

Answer (score 8):

Try this...

1. Create libs folder under your application folder.
2. Add .jar files to libs folder.
3. Then add .jar files to app's build.gradle dependency.
4. Finally Sync project with Gradle files.

**1.Create libs folder:**

[image]

**2.Add .jar to libs folder:**

[image]

**3.Edit app's build.gradle dependency:**

- Open app/build.gradle

[image]

**4.Sync project with Gradle files:**

- Finally add .jar files to your application.

[image]